# Child element not taking position command

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get my `#image-square` div to be 9px from the `#inside-preview` top. I am not sure why it isn't working. I have tried changing its position from `absolute` to `relative` as well as `top` `margin-top`, I added `block`. I don't see why it isn't working.

Help please.

```css
#outside-preview, #inside-preview {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}
#outside-preview {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
#inside-preview {
   width: 440px;
  height: 568px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left:5%;
  bottom: 0;
 }
 #image-square {
  top: 9x;
  width: 400px;
  height: 174px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="container" id="outside-preview">
    <div class="container" id="inside-preview">
       <div id="image-square"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: typo ... `9x` should be `9px`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try putting 
9px instead of 9x to start..

Comment: This was actually it. I somehow didn't type the 'p' in px. I just spent 20 minutes on this. wow.

Comment: it happens, my favorite is doing a jquery select statement and forgetting to put the "." for class or the "#" for id...

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, my answer was correct..

Comment: Not sure? I up-voted and gave you the answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions and answers are intended to serve as a useful reference for the web developer community. Aside from the OP, anybody visiting this page will not benefit from your answer, as it's based on a unique circumstance that other people won't be experiencing. You should post this type of information as a comment, and save the answer section for genuinely useful information. Because of the low level of usefulness of this question, it will likely be closed shortly.

Comment: understood, as a new user however, I was under 50 rep and unable to comment directly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you are trying to do?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRBprj

It looks like adding `margin-top:9px;` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#image-square {
    margin-top: 9px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 174px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```